# What does firebase fetchSignInMethodsForEmail return?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I'm using [RNFirebase](https://rnfirebase.io/) and want to call fetchSignInMethodsForEmail but have no idea what the format of the returned object is. Specifically, I want to check for the existence of a username-password account and a Google OAuth account. I couldn't find any info about this in the [docs](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail). Here's what happens when I console.log it:

```
{"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}
```

What do these entries represent?

Comment: You are likely looking at internal obfuscated implementation details of a JavaScript object.  That won't be helpful to you.  You should instead use the API documentation to learn about the methods and data offered by the object you have in hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick look at the [implementation of `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/4c688413cb6516ecfdbd4ea325103d0d8d8d84a8/packages/auth/android/src/main/java/io/invertase/firebase/auth/ReactNativeFirebaseAuthModule.java#L1583) (yay for open-source) it seems to return an array of the provider names. That also matches with what the native libraries do, for example the [Android variant](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/SignInMethodQueryResult).

If that is not what you seem to get, it'd be good to see the code that leads you to this result.